# Metodo put en nodejs para actualizar estado false a true

Tags: nodejs

En mi base de datos tengo un campo status que esta por defecto "false", estoy haciendo la funcion en la API aun, cuando haga click en un boton se cambie el valor a "true", tengo el siguiente esquema pero la verdad es que ya me perdi en el metodo put

```
router.put('/records/delete/:id', async(req,res)=>{
const records = await Records.find();

res.json('recibido');});
```

Este es mi esquema de la base de datos y quiero actualizar el campo status a "true" cuando presione un boton

```
const RecordsSchema = new Schema({
cod_history: {type: String, required: true},
name_person: {type: String, required: true},
specialty: {type: String, required: true},
office: {type: String, required: true},
date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
status: {type: Boolean, default: false}});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Records', RecordsSchema);
```

Comment: Hace falta demasiada información para saber como ayudarte, cuál es tu ORM y a que dialecto esta apuntando? para que estas usando la variable newRecords?

Comment: Una pregunta, donde tienes el problema, en la query que haces a la base de datos o en como enviar  y/o recibirla la petición?

Comment: Mi duda es si ese campo "status" que tiene el valor "false" por defecto, tengo que actualizarlo a "true" desde el servidor en nodejs o desde react??

Comment: @Nik a mi parecer sería mandar el status desde el cliente, así en el server solo modificas con el valor que te llega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
router.put('/records/delete', async(req,res)=>{
const records = await Records.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,
    { status: req.body.status },
    { new: true }
  );

res.json({ records });

});
```

Mongoose tiene un método que te busca y modifica el campo que quieras en base a otro campo que quieras, en este caso por el id, en el ejemplo modifica el status a true.
En campo `{new:true}` love pasas para que te regrese el documento modificado y se asigna a la variable `records`, si no lo necesitas simplemente lo quitas.